# Developing website monitoring tool using asp.net hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis, monitoring

We are planning to develop a asp.net website to monitor websites hosted on IIS servers.

Basically we want to know if websites are up and running, how is the performance and if it is down.

Is there any way we can develop this using asp.net ?

What are the services we can consume to get the status ?

We are not looking for any monitoring products available in the market out there.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to recommend which API/libraries you should use. That's what you should learn from search engines and come back with specific questions.

Answer (score -1):

This should pretty much all be possible using [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration)

Here are some use case examples that seem to match what you're describing:

```
    ServerManager server = new ServerManager();
     
    SiteCollection sites = server.Sites;
    foreach (Site site in sites)
    {
        ApplicationDefaults defaults = site.ApplicationDefaults;
     
        //get the name of the ApplicationPool under which the Site runs
        string appPoolName = defaults.ApplicationPoolName;
     
        ConfigurationAttributeCollection attributes =  defaults.Attributes;
        foreach (ConfigurationAttribute configAttribute in attributes)
        {
            //put code here to work with each ConfigurationAttribute
        }
     
        ConfigurationAttributeCollection attributesCollection = site.Attributes;
        foreach (ConfigurationAttribute attribute in attributesCollection)
        {
            //put code here to work with each ConfigurationAttribute
        }
     
        //Get the Binding objects for this Site
        BindingCollection bindings = site.Bindings;
        foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding binding in bindings)
        {
            //put code here to work with each Binding
        }
     
        //retrieve the State of the Site
        ObjectState siteState = site.State;
     
        //Get the list of all Applications for this Site
        ApplicationCollection applications = site.Applications;
        foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.Application application in applications)
        {
            //put code here to work with each Application
        }
    }
```

[Source](https://johnlnelson.com/2014/06/15/the-microsoft-web-administration-namespace/)

Comment: Unfortunately MWA does not provide any insights into performance related items.